# Relation between power, voltage and current

Tags: voltage, power, current, ac, industrial

I just started work in an industrial food manufacturing company, and they ask me what will happen to current if voltage increases in an industrial setting. I answer with OHM's law which state that current is direct proportional to voltage and inversely proportional to resistance. Going back to the question I answered that current should increase as voltage increase. But my workmates laugh at me and say I should go back to the basics of electricity. Why is that is OHM's law not applicable in industrial setting?

Comment: What did your workmates say when you politely asked them for the reason?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm's_law#Reactive_circuits_with_time-varying_signals

Answer (score 1):

Ohm's law is applicable always in any setting.

But your loads are not always resistors.

For example if you have a device like a computer that requires 500W of power from mains plug to work, it requires 500W regardless of if your mains plug provides 110V or 220V.

Answer (score 1):

Ohm's law only holds if the load is *ohmic*, for which current is indeed proportional to voltage. However, most passive and active devices are not ohmic, and do not follow Ohm's law. Some devices that are non-ohmic include:

power supplies(provide constant voltage with changing current

current/voltage sources

diodes

LEDs

motors, etc

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what they mean by "industrial setting", which does not have a rigorous definition in electrical engineering. Your statement of Ohm's law is correct for fixed resistances: V = IR, but I suspect that your colleagues may be referring to devices that can operate over a range of voltages and incorporate switchmode power supplies. In these devices, the power input is constant, or nearly so and since P = IV, as the supplied voltage increases, the current consumed decreases. In any case, saying it's an "industrial setting" isn't enough of a hint to make this obvious - and you can tell your colleagues an electrical engineer told you so!

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the setting the Ohm's law holds:

$$
V = I \cdot Z
$$

and

$$
V_{rms}=I_{rms} \cdot |Z|
$$

\$Z\$ represents the impedance that the voltage is applied across. It can be pure resistance or a combination of resistors and reactive components (inductors and capacitors). Some complex devices can be "modelled" as "capacitive" or "inductive" loads, and the \$Z\$ above includes them.

In your case, the entire system may consist of the following:

- Motors/machines (inductive loads)
- PCs (Power-factor-corrected devices, so can be considered as resistive)
- Compensation panels (make the entire system seen as resistive but the controller is capacitive)
- Fluorescent bulbs along with ballasts (inductive loads)
- LED bulbs (capacitive loads if not power-factor-corrected)
- Incandescent bulbs (resistive loads)
- Kitchen equipment (capacitive or inductive loads)
- Electricity meters (capacitive loads)
- And many others

All the items above are connected in parallel to make the \$Z\$ above.

---

The thing is, if \$Z\$ was constant (or at least, constant over a long period of time) then your answer would be correct. However, \$Z\$ doesn't have to be constant. PCs, most LED and fluorescent bulbs, and some other devices tend to keep the power drawn from the input constant. This makes the \$Z\$ a dynamic thing.

---

So the correct answer should be "depends".